# TextBlock with binding not updated on property change

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, dependency-properties, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app I have a TextBlock, which should display a (formatted) date, that is bound to a property in the view model:

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource summaryTextStyleHighlight}" Margin="0,10,0,0"
               Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentDisplayDay, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=d, Mode=OneWay}"
               Name="lblCurrentDate" />
```

The converter is "configured" in the XAML like this:

```
<local:DateFormatConverter x:Key="DateFormatConverter" />
```

And the converter class is as followed:

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            return dt.ToString((string)parameter, Utils.GetCurrentCultureInfo());
        }
        return dt.ToString("g", Utils.GetCurrentCultureInfo());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel has a simple property for the DateTime value that is bound:

```
public DateTime CurrentDisplayDay
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

But when I update the value in the ViewModel, the value won't get updated in the TextBlock on the (Main)Page.

I tried to move the property to the page, but that didn't help. If I refresh the page (navigate to it again), then the updated value is being displayed but I don't want to navigate to it, it should show the updated value through the binding.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Data binding isn't magic. There has to be some mechanism for a consumer of data to be notified that data's changed. I.e. an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See marked duplicate.

Comment: Now, I know that - didn't realised that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Patric You seem to be doing almost everything correctly, but you have forgotten about one step.

Is there any notification indicating that your property has been updated, when its value changes? You need to propagate a notification to the UI indicating that your ViewModel property has been altered, because otherwise even though the Text Dependency property is actively listening for any notification from the "source" (you have defined the binding as `One-Way`), you are simply not communicating anything to it.

Your ViewModel should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, which exposes the `PropertyChanged` event. 
The property changed event will be responsible for communicating the update.

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

On your property setter, you simply have to invoke this method, which will consequently be responsible for invoking the PropertyChanged event, with the appropriate event data.

### Edit:

In order to use the `CallerMemberName` Attribute (which allows you to get the name of the property which called the method) use the following namespace `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`

Comment: Thanks, I actually had such a method in my ViewModel because I saw it once in an example but I didn't realise that I must call this method in the setters. I thought that in UWP the binding would watch the properties somehow themselves.